# Cannot mount exFAT even though I installed exfat-fuse

Tags: mount, lubuntu

So, I installed exFAT support (Lubuntu 14.04) and it all works fine in a file manager (PCManFM), but I want to mount a disk in terminal, and it says exFAT is not found? It must be if its mounted though, right?

```
$> sudo mount -t exfat -o uid=plex,gid=nogroup /dev/sdc /media/chris/plex_disk/ 
FUSE exfat 1.0.1
ERROR: exFAT file system is not found.
```

I installed it manually using aptitude:

```
apt-get install -y exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Any help gratefuly received, Chris

Comment: I had to mount my FAT32 in FreeBSD as msdosfs since the FAT32 partition was made and formatted using a utility that was not from Microsoft. I needed to use exfat for FAT32 partitions formatted inside MSWindows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad, my mount command was incorrect.

Should've been

```
$> sudo mount -t exfat -o uid=plex,gid=nogroup /dev/sdc1 /media/chris/plex_disk/
```

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, feel free to mark it as such or (if you don't think it'll benefit anyone else) delete it.

Comment: Sorry, I had to wait, and then I forgot. Done.

Comment: Just to clarify the situation, having just tripped over this message myself, it doesn't indicate no exFAT support, it indicates that an exFAT filesystem wasn't found on the device specified. So Chris was pointing at the whole drive rather than the partition holding the filesystem.